# How to implement bridge pattern when implementation varies with abstraction

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns

I was going through the example given in this page. (A scheduler and a OS), https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/bridge.

This got me thinking, that each Operating System, will have a unique implementation of scheduling algorithms. Example, Windows will have an implementation for the Preemptive scheduler, and Time Sliced Scheduler, Unix will have an implementation of Preemptive and time sliced and so on.

So while calling a scheduler, we will also have to specify, along with implementation, the algorithm. Which will require implementing both algorithms, and passing a flag to decide which algorithm to call.

Will this actually be bridge pattern? or just a special case of adapter pattern.
If so, Is the example given actually correct with respect to implementation details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It follows bridge pattern and implemented exactly what bridge pattern is supposed to do.

The idea behind the bridge pattern is to separate abstraction from implementation so that the two can vary independently.

According to the example, In case if new schedulers or new platforms are introduced in future then the changes are very minimal.

Adaptive pattern makes two unrelated interfaces work together.

eg: I want to sort an array of numbers.

We have sort functionality implemented already which accepts list as input, but in my case the elements are in the form of array.

We can write an adapter which converts array to list to sort the elements and similary converts the result list to array.